# Failure to restart the OS through Python program which is running through services

Tags: shutdown, systemd, services, python3

I have written a Python program to restart the server running on Ubuntu 18.04 using: `os.system("shutdown -r -t 1")`.

When the service is loaded the program OS is not restarting, but on the independent running of the program it is working fine.

The service log shows:

```
Nov 18 12:51:51 jetson-desktop python3[13004]: Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Nov 18 12:51:51 jetson-desktop python3[13004]: Failed to call ScheduleShutdown in logind, proceeding with immediate shutdown: Interactive authentication required.
Nov 18 12:52:44 jetson-desktop python3[13004]: Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Interactive authentication required.
Nov 18 12:52:44 jetson-desktop python3[13004]: Failed to call ScheduleShutdown in logind, proceeding with immediate shutdown: Interactive authentication required.
```

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `shutdown` command requires elevated privileges.

Imagine, in a multi user environment, which a Linux system is, every logged in user could shutdown or reboot the machine - this would be fatal.

So, basically you need to get elevated privileges.

This question has been answered many times. Here is a good thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/use-sudo-without-password-inside-a-script